# No error, but empty dataframe resulting from webscraping real estate website with R

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape content from immobilienscout24.de and I used an instruction found here https://smac-group.github.io/ds/section-web-scraping-in-r.html .

My code runs without an error, but all I retrieve is an emtpy data.frame ("No data available in table").

I tried examples from stackoverflow, but I also end up with empty data frames. Why is that? Can someone please help me scrape the content from the website mentioned above?

I am interested in the real estates address, number of rooms, price etc.

Here is the code:

```
library("xml2")

real_estate <- read_html(
  "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/radius/wohnung-kaufen?centerofsearchaddress=Wangels;23758;Testorf;;;&geocoordinates=54.24565;10.77587;10.0&sorting=2&enteredFrom=result_list"
)

library("rvest")
library("magrittr")
flats <- real_estate %>% 
  html_nodes(".result-list-entry__data") %>%
  html_text()

flats_df <- data.frame(
  rooms = gsub(pattern = " room.*", "", flats) %>%
    as.numeric(),
  price = gsub(".*€ |.—.*", "", flats) %>%
    gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = "") %>%
    as.numeric()
)
```

I have tried some other code with a different website (same domain) and again, I retrieve an emtpy dataframe. Also the number of rows make no sense, there should be about 120...

```
pacman::p_load(rvest, dplyr) 

real <- data.frame()

for(page in seq (from = 1, to = 6, by = 1)){
  link <- paste0("https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/baden-wuerttemberg/freudenstadt-kreis/wohnung-kaufen?sorting=2&pagenumber=",page)
  code <- read_html(link) 
  Adresse <- code %>% html_node(".font-normal")%>% html_text()
  Preis <- code %>% html_node(".result-list-entry__primary-criterion:nth-child(1) .font-highlight")%>% html_text()
  Qm <- code %>% html_node(".result-list-entry__primary-criterion:nth-child(2) .font-highlight")%>% html_text()
  Zimmer <- code %>% html_node(".font-tabular .onlyLarge")%>% html_text()
  
  real=rbind(real,data.frame(
    Adresse = ifelse(length(Adresse)==0,NA,Adresse),
   Preis = ifelse(length(Preis)==0,NA,Preis),
    Qm = ifelse(length(Qm)==0,NA,Qm),
    Zimmer = ifelse(length(Zimmer)==0,NA,Zimmer)))
  
  write.csv(real, "DatensatzImmobilien.csv")   
}
```

```
Output: 
  Adresse Preis   Qm Zimmer
1    <NA>  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
2    <NA>  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
3    <NA>  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
4    <NA>  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
5    <NA>  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
6    <NA>  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
```

Comment: As of "why" , this is the content that they send out to rvest - https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5bPD.png .  You can check with e.g. `real_estate %>% html_elements("body") %>% html_text2() %>% cat()`

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my understanding, you need to use RSelenium or RDCOMClient. You have to wait for the page to load. Here is an example :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/radius/wohnung-kaufen?centerofsearchaddress=Wangels;23758;Testorf;;;&geocoordinates=54.24565;10.77587;10.0&sorting=2&enteredFrom=result_list"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)

doc <- IEApp$document()
doc$parentWindow()$execScript("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);", "javascript")
web_Obj <- doc$querySelector('#resultListItems')
info <- strsplit(web_Obj$innerText(), "\r\n")[[1]]
info[info != ""][1 : 49]

  [1] "1/11"                                                                                               
  [2] "NEU"                                                                                                
  [3] "NEUGroße Eigentumswohnung mit Gartennutzung"                                                        
  [4] "Schönwalde am Bungsberg, Ostholstein (Kreis)"                                                       
  [5] "169.000 €Kaufpreis96 m²Wohnfläche4 Zi.4Zi."                                                         
  [6] "Balkon/Terrasse"                                                                                    
  [7] "Einbauküche"                                                                                        
  [8] "Garten"                                                                                             
  [9] "..."                                                                                                
 [10] "Herr Christian Ilgautz"                                                                             
 [11] "Gläser Immobilien Neustadt"                                                                         
 [12] "1/9"                                                                                                
 [13] "NEU"                                                                                                
 [14] "Nur hier gefunden"                                                                                  
 [15] "NEUKapitalanlage - Vermietete ETW in Oldenburg i H."                                                
 [16] "Oldenburg in Holstein, Ostholstein (Kreis)"                                                         
 [17] "99.000 €Kaufpreis79 m²Wohnfläche3 Zi.3Zi."                                                          
 [18] "Nur hier gefunden"                                                                                  
 [19] "Balkon/Terrasse"                                                                                    
 [20] "Einbauküche"                                                                                        
 [21] "..."                                                                                                
 [22] "Heike Steinwender"                                                                                  
 [23] "Steinwender Immobilien"                                                                             
 [24] "1/14"                                                                                               
 [25] "Grundriss"                                                                                          
 [26] "Eigentumswohnung mit Blick ins Grüne. Nur 5 Minuten zur Ostsee."                                    
 [27] "Blekendorf, Plön (Kreis)"                                                                           
 [28] "159.000 €Kaufpreis42 m²Wohnfläche2 Zi.2Zi."                                                         
 [29] "Balkon/Terrasse"                                                                                    
 [30] "Einbauküche"                                                                                        
 [31] "Oliver Bonow"                                                                                       
 [32] "Premium Immobilien Nord GmbH"                                                                       
 [33] "1/9"                                                                                                
 [34] "360°-Ansicht"                                                                                       
 [35] "Großzügige Wohnung mit Balkon sucht neue Eigentümer!"                                               
 [36] "Oldenburg in Holstein, Ostholstein (Kreis)"                                                         
 [37] "178.500 €Kaufpreis78,74 m²Wohnfläche4 Zi.4Zi."                                                      
 [38] "Balkon/Terrasse"                                                                                    
 [39] "Keller"                                                                                             
 [40] "Herr Tobias Schirmer"                                                                               
 [41] "Postbank Immobilien GmbH - FG Kiel"                                                                 
 [42] "1/11"                                                                                               
 [43] "Stilsicher kernsanierte 4-Zimmer-Eigentumswohnung im Herzen von Schönwalde, unweit der Ostsee!"     
 [44] "Schönwalde am Bungsberg, Ostholstein (Kreis)"                                                       
 [45] "269.000 €Kaufpreis96 m²Wohnfläche4 Zi.4Zi."                                                         
 [46] "Balkon/Terrasse"                                                                                    
 [47] "Einbauküche"                                                                                        
 [48] "Garten"                                                                                             
 [49] "..."
```

Comment: Did you give time to the page to load?

Comment: What is the content of the variable web_Obj$innerText() on your end?